# Are differential rings monoids in a monoidal category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, monoidal-categories

$\newcommand{\pt}{\mathrm{pt}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$A number of algebraic structures can be defined as monoids in some appropriate monoidal category:

- A **monoid**                          is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Sets},\times,\pt)$;
- A **semiring**                        is a monoid in $(\mathsf{CMon},\otimes_{\N},\N)$;
- A **ring**                            is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Ab},\otimes_\Z,\Z)$;
- An **$R$-algebra**                    is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Mod}_R,\otimes_R,R)$;
- A **graded $R$-algebra**              is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Gr}_\Z\mathsf{Mod}_R,\otimes_R,R)$;
- A **differential graded $R$-algebra** is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(\mathsf{Mod}_R),\otimes_R,R)$.

Is this also the case for [differential rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra)?

Comment: Differential rings, yes. The rest I bet no.

Comment: Do you have a reference for differential rings? (I bet the same, by the way.)

Comment: Instead of a reference, why not take as an exercise to construct the correct monoidal category for differential rings yourself?

Comment: @mme I hadn't realised then how simple that would be (mostly because I never really worked _why_ DGAs are monoids in chain complexes). I've recorded it in an answer below and [split](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402815) the rest of the question. Thanks for the suggestion! (And thanks for the  confirmation that this can be done, Fernando!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}\newcommand{\Mod}{\mathrm{Mod}}\newcommand{\pt}{\mathrm{pt}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\dAb}{\mathsf{End}(\mathsf{Ab})}$DGAs are monoids in chain complexes. To get differential rings as monoids in some monoidal category, it suffices to remove the grading and the $\d^{2}=0$ condition.

In detail, consider the category $\mathsf{End}(\mathsf{Ab})\defeq\mathsf{Fun}(\mathbf{B}\N,\mathsf{Ab})$ whose

- Objects are pairs $(A,\d)$ with $A$ an abelian group and $d\colon A\to A$ a morphism of abelian groups.
- Morphisms $(A,\d_A)\to(B,\d_B)$ are morphisms of abelian groups preserving the derivation, i.e. such that the diagram
  $$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
  A @>\d_A>> A\\
  @V f V V @VV f V\\
  B @>>\d_B> B
  \end{CD}
  $$
  commutes.

We can then put a monoidal structure $\otimes_\Z$ on $\dAb$ by defining
$$(A,\d_A)\otimes(B,\d_B)=(A\otimes_\Z B,\d_A\otimes_\Z1_B+1_A\otimes_\Z\d_B),$$
where the unit is given by the pair $(\Z,\d_\Z)$ with $\d_\Z\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} 0$. Note that a morphism in $\dAb$ from $(\Z,\d_\Z)$ to $(A,\d_A)$ is just a "constant" element of $A$, i.e. an element with $\d_A a = 0$.

A monoid in $(\dAb,\otimes_\Z,(\Z,\d_\Z))$ will then be a triple $((A,\d),\mu,\eta)$ with

- $(A,\d)$ an object of $\dAb$; this accounts for the underlying additive abelian group of a differential ring and the derivation $\d$, which is $\Z$-linear;
- $\mu\colon(A,\d_A)\otimes_\Z(A,\d_A)\to(A,\d_A)$ a morphism of $\dAb$; this accounts for the multipication and the Leibniz rule: asking for the diagram
  $$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
  A\otimes_\Z A @>\d_A\otimes_\Z1_A+1_A\otimes_\Z\d_A>> A\otimes_\Z A\\
  @V \mu V V @VV \mu V\\
  A @>>\d_A> A
  \end{CD}
  $$
  to commute is equivalent to asking
  $$\d(ab)=\d(a)b+a\d(b)$$
  to hold for all $a,b\in A$;
- $\eta\colon(\Z,\d_\Z)\to(A,\d_A)$ a morphism of $\dAb$, determining an element $1_A$ of $A$;

such that the usual associativity and unitality diagrams commute, which makes $(A,\mu,\eta)$ into a ring, and together with $\d$, this makes the quadruple $((A,\d),\mu,\eta)$ into a differential ring.

Comment: $\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}$Here's a happy coincidence: the original question asked also whether we can view $\psi$-rings as monoids in a monoidal category. As [Gabriel C. Drummond-Cole pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/q/402815), we can, and actually this is done in a similar way to the above: while differential rings are monoids in $\mathsf{Fun}(\bf{B}\N,\mathsf{Ab})$ with $\N\defeq(\N,+,0)$, it turns out that $\psi$-rings are monoids in $\mathsf{Fun}\left(\mathbf{B}\N_{\geq1},\mathsf{Ab}\right)$ wiith $\N_{\geq1}\defeq(\N_{\geq1},\cdot,1)$!

Comment: +1 for this (research) exercise. BTW, what are $\mathbf{B}\N$ and $\mathtt{Fun}(\bullet,\bullet)$ ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Thanks! Here $\mathbf{B}A$ is the delooping of a monoid $A$, the category having only one object $\star$ and with $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{B}A}(\star,\star)\cong A$, where the composition and identity maps come from the multiplication and unit maps of $A$. The notation $\mathsf{Fun}(1,2)$ denotes the category of functors and natural transformations from $1$ to $2$. In particular, when $1=\mathbf{B}A$, it turns out that a functor $\mathbf{B}A\to\mathcal{C}$ is precisely an object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ together with a morphism of monoids $A\to\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,X)$.

Comment: For example, when $A=\mathbb{N}$, such a morphism is precisely an element of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,X)$, i.e. an endomorphism of $X$! Similarly, for $A=\mathbb{Z}$, such a morphism corresponds precisely to an invertible element of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,X)$, i.e. an automorphism of $X$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$By the way, there's a small lie in the above similarity between differential rings and $\psi$-rings, which I hadn't realised back when I wrote my first comment above: the tensor product of $(A,\d_A)$ and $(B,\d_B)$ in $\mathsf{Fun}(\mathbf{B}\mathbb{N},\mathsf{Ab})$ has $\d_{A\otimes B}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\d_A\otimes1_B+1_A\otimes\d_B$, whereas the tensor product in $\mathsf{Fun}(\mathbf{B}\mathbb{N}_{\geq1},\mathsf{Ab})$ has $\psi^{n}_{A\otimes B}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\psi^{n}_{A}\otimes\psi^{n}_{B}$, rather than

Comment: $\psi^{n}_{A\otimes B}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\!\!\!\!\!\!/\,\,\,\psi^{n}_{A}\otimes1_B+1_A\otimes\psi^{n}_{B}$.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answers. Let me some time to digest them.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. It's my pleasure!

Comment: I find this construction really beautiful. +1

Comment: @Emily I am not (yet :) a specialist in categories and trying to understand your comment above [For example, when $=\mathbb{N}$, such a morphism is precisely an element of $Hom_C(,)$, i.e. an endomorphism of ] ---> did you mean "an endomorphism of infinite order" ? (just to clarify)

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Sorry for taking a while to reply! It can be of infinite order, though it doesn't need to be so. This is because every morphism of monoids from $\mathbb{N}$ is completely determined by where $1\in\mathbb{N}$ goes to, as we have $f(n)=f(1+\cdots+1)=f(1)+\cdots+f(1)=nf(1)$ by the monoid morphism conditions. So if $(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,X),\circ,\mathrm{id}_{X})$ was e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/2$, then we'd have two different monoids morphisms from $\mathbb{N}$ to it, corresponding to whether we send $1$ to $0$ or to $1\in\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: A different way to phrase this is to say that $\mathbb{N}$ is the free monoid on the punctual set $\mathrm{pt}=\{*\}$, as monoid morphisms $\mathbb{N}\to A$ are the same as maps of sets $\mathrm{pt}\to|A|$. (We can actually even _define_ $\mathbb{N}$ in this way, and in other contexts this tends to give a host of other "fundamental objects" like $\mathbb{N}$. E.g. if we replace monoids by groups, then we get $\mathbb{Z}$, and if we replace monoids by $\infty$-groups, the homotopical version of groups, then we get the sphere spectrum :)

Comment: @Emily (+1+1) Thank you for unfolding your knowledge. Let me some time ...

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. It's my pleasure! :)