# Are PD-, $\lambda$-, $\psi$-, and $\delta$-rings monoids in a monoidal category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, monoidal-categories

$\newcommand{\pt}{\mathrm{pt}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$A number of algebraic structures can be defined as monoids in some appropriate monoidal category:

- A **monoid**                          is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Sets},\times,\pt)$;
- A **semiring**                        is a monoid in $(\mathsf{CMon},\otimes_{\N},\N)$;
- A **ring**                            is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Ab},\otimes_\Z,\Z)$;
- An **$R$-algebra**                    is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Mod}_R,\otimes_R,R)$;
- A **graded $R$-algebra**              is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Gr}_\Z\mathsf{Mod}_R,\otimes_R,R)$;
- A **differential graded $R$-algebra** is a monoid in $(\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(\mathsf{Mod}_R),\otimes_R,R)$;
- A **differential ring**              [is](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402789) a monoid in abelian groups with endomorphisms.

Is this also the case for the following notions of "rings with power operations"?

1. PD-rings ([nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/divided+power+algebra), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_power_structure)), triples $(A,I,\gamma_n)$ with $\gamma_n\colon I\to I$ satisfying e.g. (but not only)
   $$\gamma_{n}(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\gamma_{n-k}(x)\gamma_{k}(y);$$
2. $\lambda$-rings ([nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lambda-ring), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9B-ring)), pairs $(A,\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_n$ satisfying e.g. (but not only)
   $$\lambda^{n}(x+y)=\sum_{i+j=n}\lambda^i(x)\lambda^j(y);$$
3. [$\psi$-rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2976), pairs $(A,\psi_n)$ with $\psi_n$ satisfying e.g. (but not only)
   $$\psi^n\psi^m(x)=\psi^{nm}(x);$$
4. [$\delta$-rings](https://kskedlaya.org/prismatic/sec_delta-rings.html), pairs $(A,\delta)$ with $\delta$ satisfying e.g. (but not only)
   $$\delta(xy)=x^p\delta(y)+y^p\delta(x)+p\delta(x)\delta(y).$$

Comment: Aren't $\psi$-rings monoids in "$\psi$-abelian groups"?

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole I think it mostly will! The only difference is that requiring multiplication to be a morphism of $\psi$-rings will require the condition
$\psi^n(ab)=\psi^n(a)\psi^n(b)$
to hold, but it seems this is often required in the definition anyway (e.g. Knutson's [$\lambda$-Rings and the Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540061847) asks for this, and other conditions, too, in p. 49)

Comment: In the reference you gave for $\psi$-rings, in Definition 3.1, it says that each $\psi^n$ is a ring homomorphism, so that requirement occurs in that definition as well. Is there a reference for a definition where that condition does not hold?

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Ah, right! Sorry, I had misread it. Thanks!

Comment: $\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}$I've noticed a happy coincidence: differential rings are monoids in $\mathsf{Fun}(\mathbf{B}\mathbb{N},\mathsf{Ab})$ with $\mathbb{N}\defeq(\mathbb{N},+,0)$, while $\psi$-rings are monoids in $\mathsf{Fun}\left(\mathbf{B}\mathbb{N}_{\geq1},\mathsf{Ab}\right)$, where $\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}\defeq(\mathbb{N}_{\geq1},\cdot,1)$!

Comment: For Emily's happy coincidence [see](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402789/are-differential-rings-monoids-in-a-monoidal-category/402816)